# Couldn't put a song into an app

Tags: iphone

Have already tried that out and failed
I put a .wav file into my app and it was fine. So I tried to put a .wav song file into the app. When runs, there's no sound coming out. ( the song is converted from .mp3 using iTunes)
Any ideas how can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

one possible reason the sound file is too large. You have different kinds of audio player in iOS some of them can only play files that are really short (something like 1-3 sec). To fix that you have to choose another player like CoreAudio.

The second possible failure is the simulator. The simulator is not always doing the same, the device do. Try running on real device and check if it's working.

// EDIT: sample code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL URLForString:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL];

[player play];
[player pause];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've already added CoreAudio framework. What else do I have to add in order to make it work properly, could you provide some sample code?